# for in loop only applying to last key in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

heres the objects to be run through :

```
var content = {

book_1: {

    nameyo: "Doctor who",
    subject: "Books",
    price: "$10,000",
    tags: ["BOOK", "FUNNY", "KIDS", "STUPID"]

},

book_2: {

    nameyo: "Chica boom",
    subject: "Books",
    price: "$10,000",
    tags: ["BOOK", "FUNNY", "KIDS", "STUPID"]

},

Album_1: {

    nameyo: "Beatles",
    subject: "Music",
    price: "$10,000",
    tags: ["MUSIC", "BEATLES", "GOOD", "STUPID"]

},

Album_2: {

    nameyo: "ACDC",
    subject: "Music",
    price: "$10,000",
    tags: ["MUSIC", "ACDC", "GOOD", "STUPID"]

}

};
```

and here's the jquery

```
function createIDForName(key) {
return key + "blah";
}
function createIDForType(key) {
return key + "okay";
}
function createIDForPrice(key){
return key+"stuff";
}

for (var key in content) {
    $(".row").append($("<div class=col-3>")).append($("<p class=name>")).append($("<p class=type>")).append($("<p class=price>"));


    $(".name").attr("id", createIDForName(key));

    $(".type").attr("id", createIDForType(key));

    $(".price").attr("id", createIDForPrice(key));

}
```

So when this all generates, it only does it for the last key in the content object, Album_2. Why is this? Or is it overriding each time? If yes, why so? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: .name, .type, .price -selectors select all the p-elements with those classes, even the ones added on the last iteration of the for-loop. So the last values will be added to each of the p-elements.

Comment: Well, `$(".name")` matches all elements with the class `name`, not just the one you appended, but the others you've appended before as well, so you end up with the same values for all of them

Comment: most likely don't need all those ID's in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the .each() method to do this. Additionally I condensed your `createID()` functions into one function with another argument, and made the JSON valid.    [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s0vnck6q/2/)

```
var content = {
    'book_1': {
        'nameyo': "Doctor who",
        'subject': "Books",
        'price': "$10,000",
        'tags': ["BOOK", "FUNNY", "KIDS", "STUPID"]
    },
    'book_2': {
        'nameyo': "Chica boom",
        'subject': "Books",
        'price': "$10,000",
        'tags': ["BOOK", "FUNNY", "KIDS", "STUPID"]
    },
    'Album_1': {
        'nameyo': "Beatles",
        'subject': "Music",
        'price': "$10,000",
        'tags': ["MUSIC", "BEATLES", "GOOD", "STUPID"]
    },
    'Album_2': {
        'nameyo': "ACDC",
        'subject': "Music",
        'price': "$10,000",
        'tags': ["MUSIC", "ACDC", "GOOD", "STUPID"]
    }
};

function createID(key, type) {
    return key + type;
}

$.each(content, function(key, val){
    var col  = '<div class="col-3"><p class="name" id="' + createID(key, 'blah') + '"></p><p class="type" id="' + createID(key, 'okay') + '"></p><p class="price" id="' + createID(key, 'stuff') + '"></p></div>';
    $(".row").append(col);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the result you will have several dom elements with the same classes: `.name, .type, .price` and then you get them all and override their values over and over again. So in the result you have the last key values;

Answer (score 0):

The selectors `$(".name")`, `$(".price")` etc. matches all elements with the class `name`, not just the one you just appended, but the others you've appended before as well, so you end up with the same values for all of them.

To avoid that, and make life easier, just keep a reference to the elements

```
for (var key in content) {
   var _name = $('<p />', {'class' : 'name'}); //note that window.name exists
                                               // be careful with the name "name"

   _name.attr("id", createIDForName(key));
```

The easiest would be to just add the ID when the elements are created

```
for (var key in content) {
    var _col  = $('<div />', {'class' : 'col-3'}),
        _name = $('<p />', {'class' : 'name',  id : createIDForName(key)}),
        _type = $('<p />', {'class' : 'type',  id : createIDForType(key)}),
        _pric = $('<p />', {'class' : 'price', id : createIDForPrice(key)});

    $(".row").append(_col, _name, _type, _pric);
}
```